Which is the smallest FIDE federation?
Just seen Which FIDE federations has never sent a women's team to the Chess Olympiads
My thought was, what if a federations is too small, in terms of FIDE registered players, to create a team that is worth sending?  So how many federations are very small and how small are they.

Define "very small."   (+1)

@SecretAgentMan Maybe something like they don't have enough good players to make it worthwhile sending teams to international events.

It's tricky to answer this because for FIDE electoral reasons there has been a tendancy in the 2000s to create many federations in small countries that were just empty shells with very few players, as long as they provided one official delegate enjoying a free trip to Turin or Elista for the FIDE General Assembly - provided they voted for the right guy, of course.

https://i.imgur.com/6BXc10D.png this was what eventually led me to the question

Unfortunately this information, which was once easily obtained via the "Advanced Search" function on the FIDE rating website, is no longer available.
However, the raw data is made available via the FIDE Ratings Download page. I do this regularly and store the extracted data in my own database. Here are the results of a search on the smallest federations by player count and including female players (and a population count which was accurate when first entered into the database but now may be out of date).
Here are the federations with fewer than 30 players:



Federation
Players
Female players
Population




Tonga
2
0
106017


New Caledonia
3
0
269220


Congo
10
3
89767000


Belize
11
1
397621


St Kitts & Nevis
16
5
55345


Vanuatu
19
6
319137


Br. Virgin Islands
19
9
28514


Papua New Guinea
24
1
8083700


Isle of Man
24
0
85032


Cambodia
27
3
15626444


Grenada
29
9
111454




Thanks, how many federations don't have anyone over 2200?

Congrats on the 100K, Brian, thanks for all your service!
